# PyTorch Target torch size doesn't match to the input size

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, torch

I am trying to train my model on some data and the torch size is not matching. I included everything I tried lower in my post. I tried everything that I knew to try. Please help

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zyman\PycharmProjects\Neural_network_trading_bot\main.py", line 150, in <module>
    train(model, dataset, num_generations, num_networks, num_clones, batch_size, num_epochs)
  File "C:\Users\zyman\PycharmProjects\Neural_network_trading_bot\main.py", line 85, in train
    loss = criterion(outputs.view(-1), batch_targets.view(-1))
  File "C:\Users\zyman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zyman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 720, in forward
    return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target,
  File "C:\Users\zyman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3163, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
    raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([32])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([3200]))
```

This is my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x


class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_path, sequence_length):
        data = pd.read_csv('c:\\Users\\zyman\\PycharmProjects\\Pulling-Data\\NeuralNetworkTrainingData.csv', delimiter=',')
        normalized_data = (data.iloc[:, :-1] - data.iloc[:, :-1].mean()) / data.iloc[:, :-1].std()

        self.inputs = []
        self.targets = []
        for i in range(len(data) - sequence_length - 1):
            self.inputs.append(normalized_data.iloc[i:i+sequence_length].values)
            close_price = data.iloc[i+sequence_length]['close']
            open_price = data.iloc[i+sequence_length]['open']
            if close_price > open_price:
                self.targets.extend([1] * sequence_length)  # Green candle
            else:
                self.targets.extend([0] * sequence_length)  # Red candle

        self.inputs = np.array(self.inputs)
        self.targets = np.array(self.targets)


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return torch.tensor(self.inputs[index], dtype=torch.float32), torch.tensor(self.targets[index], dtype=torch.float32)



def train(model, dataset, num_generations, num_networks, num_clones, batch_size, num_epochs):
    for generation in range(num_generations):
        print(f"Generation: {generation + 1}")
        print("Training...")

        top_performers = []

        for network_index in range(num_networks):
            print(f"Network: {network_index + 1}")
            model_clone = Net(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
            model_clone.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())

            dataset_size = len(dataset)
            train_size = int(0.8 * dataset_size)
            train_set, val_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, dataset_size - train_size])

            train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
            val_loader = DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

            criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
            optimizer = optim.Adam(model_clone.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

            best_val_accuracy = 0.0

            for epoch in range(num_epochs):
                model_clone.train()
                for batch_inputs, batch_targets in train_loader:
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    outputs = model_clone(batch_inputs)
                    loss = criterion(outputs.view(-1), batch_targets.view(-1))
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()

                model_clone.eval()
                correct_predictions = 0
                total_predictions = 0

                with torch.no_grad():
                    for val_inputs, val_targets in val_loader:
                        val_outputs = model_clone(val_inputs)
                        val_predictions = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(val_outputs))
                        correct_predictions += (val_predictions == val_targets).sum().item()
                        total_predictions += val_targets.numel()

                val_accuracy = correct_predictions / total_predictions

                if val_accuracy > best_val_accuracy:
                    best_val_accuracy = val_accuracy
                    model.load_state_dict(model_clone.state_dict())

            top_performers.append(model_clone)

        print("Evaluation...")
        correct_predictions = 0
        total_predictions = 0

        with torch.no_grad():
            for inputs, targets in dataset:
                outputs = model(inputs.unsqueeze(0))
                predictions = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(outputs))
                correct_predictions += (predictions == targets).sum().item()
                total_predictions += targets.numel()

        accuracy = correct_predictions / total_predictions
        print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

        if generation < num_generations - 1:
            top_performers = sorted(top_performers, key=lambda m: -best_val_accuracy)[:num_clones]
            model_clones = [Net(input_size, hidden_size, output_size) for _ in range(num_networks)]

            for i, performer in enumerate(top_performers):
                for j in range(num_clones):
                    model_clones[i * num_clones + j].load_state_dict(performer.state_dict())

            model = nn.Sequential(*model_clones)

        print("=" * 50)


input_size = 4
hidden_size = 64
output_size = 10
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 10
sequence_length = 10
num_generations = 100
num_networks = 100
num_clones = 10


model = Net(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
dataset = CustomDataset('c:\\Users\\zyman\\PycharmProjects\\Pulling-Data\\NeuralNetworkTrainingData.csv', sequence_length)

train(model, dataset, num_generations, num_networks, num_clones, batch_size, num_epochs)
```

I tried adjusting the batch size, and the target size is two 0 less than the input size. For example: target size 32, input size 3200.

Comment: What's the nature of your data? What's the shape of `batch_inputs` and `batch_targets `?

Comment: the data is in a .csv file

Answer (score 0):

1. `T.view(-1)` flatten the tensor `T` so calling `criterion(outputs.view(-1), batch_targets.view(-1))` will flatten your outputs and targets before applying criterion.
2. Here criterion is BCEWithLogitsLoss [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html). It takes the logits as inputs, so the raw outputs of the model (and without sigmoid!) instead of flat vectors.

So remove the sigmoid, remove the `view(-1)` in the criterion call and finally I guess your targets are sparse values (1, 2, 3, ...) so you should one-hot encode them to make them compatible with logits: `batch_targets = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(batch_targets, output_size)` in the data processing.